# JAVA, public static variables initialization

Tags: java, static, initialization

```
/* ---------------------- classes --------------- */

public class A {
  public static String str = "compile";
      public A() {
  }
}

public class B {
  public static String str = A.str;

  public B() {
  }
}

/* ----------------------------------------------- */

/* ------------ main class --------------------- */

public class C {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A.str = "runtime";
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();

    // comment at the first, and comment this out next time
    //A.str = "runtime2";

    System.out.println(A.str);
    System.out.println(a.str);
    System.out.println(B.str);
    System.out.println(b.str);
  }
}

/* --------------------------------------------- */
```

results is like this....

1. with comment :
   runtime
   runtime
   runtime
   runtime
2. without comment :
   runtime2
   runtime2
   runtime
   runtime

I understand in A's case, 
but i don't in B's case.
Would you please explain about this?

Answer (score 2):

At the first appearance of `A` in your code, `A.str` gets initialized to "compile", but then it gets immediately overwritten with "runtime".

Then you declare your `a` and `b` instances.  But this is where class `B` is referenced for the first time, so it gets initialized *here* to `A.str`, which is currently "runtime".

In your commented code,

```
//A.str = "runtime2";
```

This would change only `A.str`; `B.str` would still refer to "runtime".  And it is possible to access a static variable with either the classname `A.str` or an instance `a.str`.

Answer (score 1):

Classes in java are [loaded and initialized when](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) they are accessed for the first time.

So here what happens in your main method:

1. you write `A.str = ...` : at this point (before the assignment happens) the class `A` is loaded and initialized, the variable `str` holds the string `"compile"`
2. after `A.str = "runtime";` the old value `"compile"` is overriden
3. `A a = new A();` does not change anything
4. with `B b = new B();` the class `B` get loaded too and initialized. the value of `B.str` get the actual value of `A.str`

this is what explains the first output: `runtime` all the way

now you uncoment  `A.str = "runtime2";`, only the variable `str` in class `A` is changed. `B.str` remain on `runtime`.

this is what explains the second output.